# Linq Any() times out

Tags: asp.net, linq, .net-4.5

I am trying to compare two data tables using Linq. Very simple tables, just one column but have about 44,000 rows. I use the following but when I trace it, when it gets to if (dr.Any()), it just sits there and next line, or exception, is never executed:

```
public static DataTable GetTableDiff(DataTable dt1, DataTable dt2)
{
    DataTable dtDiff = new DataTable();
    try
    {
        var dr = from r in dt1.AsEnumerable() where !dt2.AsEnumerable().Any(r2 => r["FacilityID"].ToString().Trim().ToLower() == r2["FacilityID"].ToString().Trim().ToLower()) select r;

        if (dr.Any())
            dtDiff = dr.CopyToDataTable();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }
    return dtDiff;
}
```

I set max request length in web.config to make sure that is not an issue, but no change:

```
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" maxRequestLength="1048576" />
```

I don't think 44,000 rows is too big, is it?

Comment: [maxRequestLength](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e1f13641%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) `Specifies the limit for the input stream buffering threshold, in KB. This limit can be used to prevent denial of service attacks that are caused, for example, by users posting large files to the server.`  It is related to the request size and not to Linq queries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Join tables O(N1+N2) instead of doing O(N1*N2) search (currently for each row in dt1 you are scanning all rows in dt2):

```
var diff = from r1 in dt1.AsEnumerable()
           join r2 in dt2.AsEnumerable() 
               on r1.Field<string>("FacilityID").Trim().ToLower()
               equals r2.Field<string>("FacilityID").Trim().ToLower() into g
           where !g.Any() // get only rows which do not have joined rows from dt2
           select r1;
```

With join you will also calculate each key (facility id) only once.

---

Another option is creating simple row comparer:

```
public class FacilityIdComparer : IEqualityComparer<DataRow>
{
    public bool Equals(DataRow x, DataRow y) => GetFacilityID(x) == GetFacilityID(y);
    public int GetHashCode(DataRow row) => GetFacilityID(row)?.GetHashCode() ?? 0;
    private string GetFacilityID(DataRow row)
        => row.Field<string>("FacilityID")?.Trim().ToLower();
}
```

Then getting new rows is one liner with LINQ `Except` method:

```
var diff = dt2.AsEnumerable().Except(dt1.AsEnumerable(), new FacilityIdComparer());
```

and it will work for searching intersections as well

Comment: Thank you for the response. Both your solution and Tim's worked equally well but I marked yours as an answer since it was first.

Answer (score 3):

I would use a different, more leightweight, approach because you just take rows from one table and you want only those with a new `FacilityId`:

```
public static DataTable GetTableDiff(DataTable dtNew, DataTable dtOld)
{
    DataTable dtDiff = dtNew.Clone();  // no data only columns and constraints
    var oldFacilityIds = dtOld.AsEnumerable().Select(r => r.Field<string>("FacilityID").Trim());
    var oldFacilityIDSet = new HashSet<string>(oldFacilityIds, StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);

    var newRows = dtNew.AsEnumerable()
        .Where(r => !oldFacilityIDSet.Contains(r.Field<string>("FacilityID").Trim()));

    foreach (DataRow row in newRows)
        dtDiff.ImportRow(row);

    return dtDiff;
}
```